# cloud-init, virt-install and reboot

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, kvm, cloud-init

So I have a VM running on Ubuntu/KVM a cloud image (ubuntu-cloud-something, virt-install with --import option). I fed my customization to cloud-init with ISO image (SSH key, hostname, etc).

Now I need to reboot it. Questions:

1. Am I right, that I don't need any of the cloud-init stuff? I don't need to mount this CDROM ISO now?
2. How do I reboot it - what happens if I just reboot from a guest? Or should I do it from the hypervisor (which command, then?)?

Comment: 1- No you don't need the ISO anymore. ``cloud-init`` keep some semaphore in /var/lib/cloud/ on debian to run only once per instance some modules. So no need to change anything on your side.
2- No problem ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you don't need cloud-init when you restart the VM.
2. You can reboot it from the guest or you can use `virsh reboot $hostname`